# Changing words used on 'No Results' Page

Tags: search, drupal

I want to change the words 'bike', 'shed' and 'bike shed' on my 'Your search yielded no results' Drupal page. Is there anyway I can do this without editing the Drupal core? If I do have to edit the Drupal core, what file would I edit?

Any help on this appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are just wanting to replace text with other static text, take a look at the [String Overrides](http://drupal.org/project/stringoverrides) Module.  From the project page:

> Provides a quick and easy way to replace any text on the site.
>
> **Features**
>
> - Easily replace anything that's passed through t()
> - Locale support, allowing you to override strings in any language
> - Ability to import/export *.po files, for easy migration from the Locale module
> - Note that this is not a replacement to Locale as having thousands of
>     overrides can cause more pain then benefit. Use this only if you need
>     a few easy text changes.